# where to put sourceSets in multiple projects gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a multiple projects gradle, in the top gradle is

```
subprojects {

    apply plugin: "java"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            scala {
                srcDirs = ['src/main/scala', 'src/main/java']
            }
            java {
                srcDirs = []
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "http://repo.springsource.org/milestone"
        }
    }
}
```

But it complains

```
> Could not find method sourceSets() for arguments [build_vgdvugn6hqrvg7eo53afh1229$_run_closure1_closure2@19962194] on root project 'testCom'.
```

So where should I put sourceSets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is a bit misleading, but before you can configure `sourceSets.main.scala`, you'll have to apply the `scala` plugin.